# Object can not be interpreted as an index

Tags: python

When i try to use this function:

```
def dec_to_bin():
    decimal = raw_input('Input a number: ')
    a =  bin(decimal)
    print(a)
```

It gives an error:::::

```
a =  bin(decimal) TypeError: 'str' object can not be interpreted as an index
```

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The return value from `raw_input` is a `str`, not an `int`. You must first convert it to an `int` before passing it to `bin`.

```
a = bin(int(decimal))
```

This will fail with a `ValueError` if the string entered cannot be converted to an integer.